# Global temp table doesn't exist any more after calling stored procedure with this.ExecuteMethodCall in linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

First I created a temptable calling a stored procedure.

Then while trying to get the results from a second stored procedure **from the same dbcontext** I am getting an error saying the temp table doesn't exist anymore.

Here is the incomplete code.

```
    private void GetTempResult()
    {
        var tempTable = "##mytaemptable";
        //  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  Services.StartPreparingTempList(clientId,tempTable));
        // execute stored procedure to create temp table 
        Services.StartPreparingTempList(clientId, tempTable); // temptable gets created successfully here .

        // execute stored procedure to get results from the above created temp table.
        var tempResults = Services.GetPartialTempList(tempTable, jtableArgs); //getting error here . As soon as this statement gets executed the temp table ceases to exist. 
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetPartialTempEmailList")]
    public ISingleResult<JournalEmail> GetPartialTempEmailList([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="NVarChar(MAX)")] string tempTableName, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> startIndex, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> maxRowCount)
    {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), tempTableName, startIndex, maxRowCount);
            return ((ISingleResult<JournalEmail>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.StartPreparingTempList")]
    public int StartPreparingTempList([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ClientID", DbType="NVarChar(150)")] string clientID, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="NVarChar(MAX)")] string tempTableName, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> maxRowCount)
    {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), clientID, tempTableName, maxRowCount);
            return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
}
```

Do stored procedures get executed in a new connection/session with the below statement? As soon as this statement gets executed, temptable ceases to exist and throws error : invalid object name.

```
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), tempTableName, startIndex, maxRowCount);
```

Can somebody guide me what am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want to create a temp table in linq-to-sql? Might be better with importing a view?

Comment: What happens if two separate sessions execute this at the same time? Not sure why it isn't working for you, but basically because I'd move several large mountains to avoid having to do this in the first place. Problem could be in the stored proc itself...

Comment: @Arion, wanted to store temp result in some where ..and this came to my mind. Right now doing a proof of concept to get partial results later on can change storage. Might be better with imporing a view don't have much idea..:)

Comment: @Tony, right now don't need to worry about session ..just want to see the functionality working . When i cam executing the stored proc it the db with hard coded values before the stored proc is called from app it's running properly.

Comment: Interesting, what about if you execute the two procs in different sessions, I'm struggling to come up with any reason why executing the SPs from code is going to disappear anything you see. Not saying there isn't one :D just that I can't even guess why this might be happening at the moment.

Comment: @Tony, aah yes when i put a break point on the execute method and execute the stored proc from backend(from a diff session) it's running. But when the execute method gets executed the temp table ceases to exist and i get the error invalid object name.. at this point if i run the same stored proc from db it also gives same error invalid object name. Don't know what is going around which brought me to SO in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to create a global temporary table and insert values values in one store procedure(lets name it as sp1) and trying to retrieve the values in another in sp2(lets name it as sp2).
This problem happens in linqtosql(**in IExecuteResult result**) while retrieving the second store procedure (sp2).
I fixed the issue but changing the returned type of the store procedure (sp2) in the dbml file  to a class with the column name as property type which I created in the dbml designer
 or
 you can create a view or a table with same return type of the global temp table and add it to the designer. You can then use the view/table as the return type of the store procedure (sp2)

> In the picture illustration *sp_EditMVC_reconcile_fix_get_no_medical is (sp2)* which I used to retrieve the global temp table and *reconcile_no_medical_temp* is the class I created.

[image: In the picture illustration *sp_EditMVC_reconcile_fix_get_no_medical is (sp2)* which I used to retrieve the global temp table and *reconcile_no_medical_temp* is the class I created.]

[image: In the picture illustration *sp_EditMVC_reconcile_fix_get_no_medical is (sp2)* which I used to retrieve the global temp table and *reconcile_no_medical_temp* is the class I created.]

Solution 2:

I think its a bug in VS, so I can't find the logic in it and I don't have the time to find right now.

Add the SP2 query in SP1 and use the custom created class as a return type. Then the SP2 will work. Dont know the reason but it will fix it if the above solution fails.
Sorry for my bad english.
Hope it helps